# Do OS X upgrades install packages that shadow packages I'm maintaining with pip?

Tags: python, macos, pip, package

After upgrading to Mavericks (OS 10.9), I found that the locations that Apple's Python (2.7.5) was using for many packages I had installed earlier had changed,<sup>1</sup> and that several had been "downgraded" to older versions. Confusingly, I found that updating these older versions (using `pip` which I use to maintain my packages) was prevented by the presence of unused but current versions these packages,<sup>2</sup> and that deleting the new (but older) versions that Mavericks had installed was necessary.

What's going on here? Did Mavericks just come with some commonly used packages (like `mathplotlib`) that it put in the `.../Extras/...` folder where they shadow versions I had been maintaining in `.../site-packages/`? Using `pip` seems to have fixed this problem, effectively clearing out `.../Extras/...` of (often slightly old) duplicates of my packages in `.../site-packages/`, but I want to confirm that I'm doing the right thing, especially since this seems to happen every time Apple updates Python.

<sup>1: To `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`</sup>
 
<sup>2: Still present and undisturbed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`</sup>

Comment: This is not answering your question, but this is where a python virtual environment would be extremely handy. You would never have to worry about any of these weird conflict issues when updating your os or installing new packages. http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/ if you're interested in learning about it.

Comment: @btse: Yes, I should always add to such questions: "This is not a question about virtualenv."