# What is the design reason for the ordering of Python packages path?

Tags: python, path, pip, package

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14882377/656912) that, on OS X, the default ordering for searching paths for packages is (in the form reported by `pprint(sys.path)`) something like:

```
['',
 '/Library/Python/X.X/site-packages/PKGS_WITH_EGGS.egg',
 ...
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/lib/pythonX.X/SOME_PLATFORM_PKGS,
 ...
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/Extras/lib/python',
  ...
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/lib/pythonX.X/OTHER_PLATFORM_PKGS,
 ...
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
'/Library/Python/X.X/site-packages']
```

For example, on my system (OS 10.9) I have:

```
['',
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy-0.3.dev2837-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',  
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Other systems seem to adopt a similar structure.

What is the logic of this ordering, in particular why are "eggs" sought first, and why is `site-packages` used last?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the latter is done to allow updates of Python itself to be sure that the packages they come with are used (though this [creates problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19548662/656912) if these are not the latest) in preference to others that might be present; but this seems odd given that any updates using `pip` will ["move"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15363910/656912) packages to (the last-searched) `site-packages`.

Comment: My (admittedly not very good, wild) guess about the former would be that it ensures that "eggs", which are likely managed by something old and thus not "know" about whats going on with the rest of the configuration, get used.